# Splitting a row based on two column values

Tags: pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
    A   B   C   Date1       Date2
0   a   b   c   02/19/2022  02/20/2022
1  aa  bb  cc   02/26/2022  02/27/2022
```

I want to combine Date1 and Date2 into one column, and duplicate the other column values that correspond to it. Into a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    A   B   C   Date
0   a   b   c   02/19/2022
1   a   b   c   02/20/2022
2  aa  bb  cc   02/26/2022
3  aa  bb  cc   02/27/2022
```

I know how one would do this once this dataframe has been imported into SQL using join, but is there a way to do this directly in the Pandas dataframe before uploading to a database?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `pandas` offers `stack()` -  You could set the index on your 'A', 'B' and 'C' columns:

```
df.set_index(['A','B','C']).stack().droplevel(level=3).rename('Date').reset_index()
```

prints:

```
    A   B   C        Date
0   a   b   c  02/19/2022
1   a   b   c  02/20/2022
2  aa  bb  cc  02/26/2022
3  aa  bb  cc  02/27/2022
```

---

Breakdown:

```
# Setup
>>> df.to_dict()

{'A': {0: 'a', 1: 'aa'},
 'B': {0: 'b', 1: 'bb'},
 'C': {0: 'c', 1: 'cc'},
 'Date1': {0: '02/19/2022', 1: '02/26/2022'},
 'Date2': {0: '02/20/2022', 1: '02/27/2022'}}

>>> print(df)
    A   B   C       Date1       Date2
0   a   b   c  02/19/2022  02/20/2022
1  aa  bb  cc  02/26/2022  02/27/2022

# 1) Set the index -> A,B,C
a = df.set_index(['A','B','C'])

                Date
A  B  C             
a  b  c   02/19/2022
      c   02/20/2022
aa bb cc  02/26/2022
      cc  02/27/2022

# 2) Stack the DF -> Since it has one column, it will return a Series
b = a.stack()

A   B   C       
a   b   c   Date    02/19/2022
            Date    02/20/2022
aa  bb  cc  Date    02/26/2022
            Date    02/27/2022

# 3) Remove the 3rd layer of the index
# Where it says "Date", which is the result of 'Stacking'
# Try dropping another level here
c = b.droplevel(level=3)

A   B   C 
a   b   c     02/19/2022
        c     02/20/2022
aa  bb  cc    02/26/2022
        cc    02/27/2022

# Renaming the three layered series
d = c.rename('Date')

A   B   C 
a   b   c     02/19/2022
        c     02/20/2022
aa  bb  cc    02/26/2022
        cc    02/27/2022


# Converting the index to columns
e = d.reset_index()

    A   B   C        Date
0   a   b   c  02/19/2022
1   a   b   c  02/20/2022
2  aa  bb  cc  02/26/2022
3  aa  bb  cc  02/27/2022
```

Documentation of the functions used:

- [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)
- [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
- [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html)
- [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html)
- [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

Comment: is there a way to reverse the output df to the input df? I thought of it and wanted to ask if someone knows before i look into it

Comment: do you mean perform the operation ```inplace``` ? So that the initial df is modified?

Comment: lets say we run `df2 = df.setindex...` like you have above. how would we `df3 = df2....` where df3 would be the same thing/ copy of df. Not making a reference to df at all.

Comment: thank you for the answer, can i ask what droplevel does? I played around with the code for a while now and learned that stack() returns a Series. Does droplevel(level=3) just remove the 3rd column in the stacked DataFrame?

Comment: You're essentially dropping a column and renaming the one that is kept

Comment: Hi, I am sorry for the delayed response. Give me some time and I will do my best to provide a detailed answer.

Comment: @jski212002 - hopefully this now is clear. Let me know if you wish further explanation.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for a detailed explanation. I guess my only question now is how do we know which level to drop when calling droplevel? I tried playing around with the feature and changing the levels that is being dropped, and learned that it drops other columns in the dataframe as well depending on the level provided. Especially if we have a large number of columns, do we just need to manually check for the position of the unnecessary column being created by stack()?